# When Symantec Endpoint Protection and Fiddler enabled, all browser traffic fails to connect

Tags: networking, fiddler, symantec

I was debugging with Fiddler without issue until today, when Symantec Endpoint Protection was enabled.  Now, when I have both turned on, all browser traffic results in a 502 - connection failed.

Seems like something needs to be adjusted in Symantec so I can debug again.  suggestions?

Comment: Does Symantec have a "Web Filter" "Web Proxy" "Network malware filter" or similarly-named feature? If so, disable it. Also, ensure that Symantec's firewall is configured to allow traffic to/from Fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symantec Endpoint Protection, go to Network Threat Protection and check applications.  In my case, Symantec was blocking any traffic through Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SEP are you running?

Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.

In Symantec Endpoint Protection client , check under Traffic Logs under Network Threat protection if there is any traffic blocked.

You could also try disabing the Network Threat protection feature OR uninstall the feature from Add / Remove Programs and check if the Fiddler works.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Under Network Threat Protection, select "option" Then click the "change settings", uncheck checkbox "block all traffic until the firewall starts and after firewall stops" Under the firewall tab and apply. Mostly this will resolve the issue.